# azure devops docker image prune does not work as expected

Tags: docker, azure-devops

docker images created by an azure pipeline are not deleted correctly with `sudo docker image prune -a`.

The commands output tells that several images are untagged and deleted, however `total reclaimed space: 0B`.
`df` confirms that there is not any reclaimed space

`sudo docker system prune -a` however works.

I also never had any problems with deleting docker images that I created with docker in the commandline

Comment: How did you prune the image in DevOps pipeline? Can you please share the yaml file? Besides, you mentioned `sudo docker system prune -a` works, so what about adding another task to run this command in pipeline?

Comment: sorry I was not precise enough, the images were created by the docker pipline however as the available space on the server was pretty low. I logged in on server that runs the agent via ssh, as another user as the one that installed the agent if that is important, and executed the `sudo docker image prune -a` and later the `sudo docker system prune -a` command. I will try to call the commands directly from the pipeline and see if anything changes

Comment: So, it's not an Azure DevOps issue, it's more like a local Docker issue on the agent server. Anyway, you can have a try to add a step to run the command in your pipeline to see if it works.  e.g `- script: sudo docker system prune -a`

Comment: May I know any updates? Can you resolve the issue by running the command `sudo docker system prune -a` in pipeline?

Comment: @Andy Li-MSFT I now found out I can delete the Images with 'sudo docker builder prune' so that is probably the right way I will try to find out why I also works with sudo docker builder prune but not with 'sudo docker image prune'